# How to define a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to set a polymorphic association. Unfortunately, the Ember docs don't cover this too well.

My API (Rails) has the following definition:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true#, dependent: :destroy
end

class MemberProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
end

class GuestProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Which means, in Rails console, I can do `User.last.profile`, which will return either a `MemberProfile` or `GuestProfile` object.

How should I define this on the client side (Ember)?

```
// app/models/user.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  profile:      DS.belongsTo('profile', { polymorphic: true, async: true })
});

// app/models/member-profile.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  profile:      DS.belongsTo('profile', { polymorphic: true, async: true })
});

// app/models/guest-profile.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  profile:      DS.belongsTo('profile', { polymorphic: true, async: true })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the Ember Docs seem to be lacking. I don't think there's much to it, beyond the `DS.belongsTo('profile', { polymorphic: true, async: true })` that you've already outlined.

One option would be to extend a Profile class:

```
// Standard Ember code - use export/import conventions for ember-cli
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
  // Attributes here, maybe a reference to the related User
});

App.MemberProfile = App.Profile.extend({
  // Member-specific attributes
});

App.GuestProfile = App.Profile.extend({
  // Guest-specific attributes
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  profile: DS.belongsTo('profile', {polymorphic: true, async: true})
});
```

This would allow you to do `someUser.get('profile')`, and have the returned value be either a member or a guest. It is based off code provided at: http://www.toptal.com/emberjs/a-thorough-guide-to-ember-data#the-ember-data-value-proposition

You could alternatively create similarly-formed Mixins, in a situation that calls for it.

There was a related discussion on the Ember forums earlier this year related to best practices using Ember's polymorphic associations: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/cleaner-way-to-define-polymorphic-associations/6369

As a side-note, in your javascript code the `member-profile.js` and `guest-profile.js` would link to a `user`, rather than a `profile` to mimic your Rails code.